# Unable to change views using dropdown. I am able to get the dropdown but clicking does not change the view

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs

In my application there are different views, so I've a dropdown from user can change view. I'm able to view the dropdown but I'm not able to change the view by clicking it. This happens in chrome, and Opera.

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-xs" >
<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td ng-if="(view==1)">View 1</td>
            <td ng-if="(view.id==1)">View 2</td>
            <td ng-if="(view==1)">View 3</td>
            <td class="width10"><span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span><span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</button>
<ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="dropdown-submenu" ng-click="loadView(1)">
        <div class="">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>View 1</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu" ng-click="loadView(2)">
        <div class="">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>View 1</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu" ng-click="loadView(3)">
        <div class="">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>View 1</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is there a reason for not using a <select>?

Comment: And can you give as a snippet with the css and the js so we can look what exactly happens...

Comment: I need to make this dropdown with button groups to provide some more options to user.

Comment: Ok, than send us please a snippet or something else... for example here: https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

I'ts not really clear what your ng-if is doing and there is no code of your function `loadView()`. I think, you would like to pass 1 to 3 in you function as parameter and than show/hide your views with this number. Maybe this helps:

Declare in your controller a variable:

```
$scope.viewNumber = 1; //Default loading view 1
```

Than write your function like this:

```
$scope.loadView() = function(viewNr) {
    $scope.viewNumber = viewNr;
}
```

And than use the `ng-if` like this:

```
<td ng-if="viewNumber == 1">View 1, if viewNumber is 1</td>
<td ng-if="viewNumber == 2">View 2, if viewNumber is 2</td>
<td ng-if="viewNumber == 3">View 3, if viewNumber is 3</td>
```

So I'm not sure if this is the solution you looked for, but it's also not clear, what you really want to achieve... So what I do below is, declaring a variable for the view number I pass as parameter to my function when I click on a `li` element within the dropdown. Than I change the three views with this number checking it in a `ng-if`. I hope this helps you.